# Check if select options is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am running dataTables plugin for a project.

Could you please show me where I am doing it wrong (it is extremely simple and it doesn't show any errors):

```
<select name="DataTables_Table_0_length" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Basically that is what I have generated. So I want to select the 50 and 100 values to all the tables on the page and show the footer of the generated tables only when these two results are selected.

I tried the following (just for value="50"):

```
var selected_result = $('select option:nth(2)');
var tfoot = $('tfoot');
tfoot.hide();

if (selected_result.is(':selected')) { tfoot.show(); }
```

Thank you

Comment: try thus tfoot.val(50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.change()` then check if it's selected to either show/hide the footer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tfoot").hide();
    $("select").change(function() {
        if ($("select option:nth(2)").is(":selected")) {
            $("#tfoot").show();
        } else {
            $("#tfoot").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rcLrf18j/

Comment: Thank you! Worked. Why are you using change? I thought it can detect just on selection.

Comment: Because you want to check if the option is selected whenever the option is changed, then either show or hide `$("#tfoot")` by checking if an option is selected or not.

Comment: It can detect on selection, but you want to check it once it's changed. :) Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Rather than seeing if the 3rd option is selected, you can simply do `if (this.value == '50')`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  function showOptionValue() {
   var optionSelected = document.getElementById("select_test");
   var optionSelected_value = optionSelected.options[optionSelected.selectedIndex].value;
   
   alert(optionSelected_value);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <form action = "" method = "post">
   <select name = "select_test" id = "select_test" >
    <option value = "10">10</option>
    <option value = "25">25</option>
    <option value = "50">50</option>
    <option value = "100">100</option>
   </select>
   <input type = "button" value = "show option value" onclick = "showOptionValue()"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

This code show you the current value of the option when clicking on the button. I let you use this one to modify the function to do what you want to do (meaning, showing your footer).

Hope it helps !

Comment: The button's *onclick* attribute can be simply `alert(this.form.select_test.value)`. The select element doesn't need an ID attribute. But this doesn't answer the question…

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the footer is hidden by default. If you want to show the footer if either 50 or 100 are selected, then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=DataTables_Table_0_length]').change(function() {

        if (this.value == '50' || this.value == '100') {
            $("#tfoot").show();

        } else {
            $("#tfoot").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=DataTables_Table_0_length]').change(function() {
        this.value == '50' || this.value == '100'? $("#tfoot").show() : $("#tfoot").hide();
    });
});
```

or even:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=DataTables_Table_0_length]').change(function() {
        $("#tfoot")[this.value == '50' || this.value == '100'? 'show' : 'hide']()
    });
});
```